# Fetch data at startup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a treeview component in react where data for the tree is fetched based on the nodes expanded by the user.

**The idea**

When the first node is expanded a HTTP request is sent to a service which returns all of the children of that node. When another node is expanded the children of that node is fetched etc. This works with the code below.

```
function TreeNode({ id, name }) {
  const [childNodes, setChildNodes] = useState(null);

  function fetchJSON(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
      }
      return res.json();
    });
  }

  function fetchChildNodes(id) {
    return fetchJSON(`someUrl/${id}`);
  }

  const toggleExpanded = useCallback(() => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
    fetchChildNodes(id).then(result =>
      setChildNodes(result.map(node => <TreeNode {...node} />))
    );
  }, [expanded]);
}

ReactDOM.render(<TreeNode />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Problem**

On page load an initial root node should be fetched from the service. This root node should only be fetched once at startup. So I tried adding the following methods:

```
function loadDataOnlyOnce() {
    fetch(`someUrl/specficId`).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
      }
      res
        .json()
        .then(result =>
          setChildNodes(result.map(node => <TreeNode {...node} />))
        );
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadDataOnlyOnce();
  }, []);
```

But nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Define "Nothing happens". Does your `loadDataOnlyOnce()` never gets called?

Comment: The ´loadDataOnlyOnce´ gets called at startup, but nothing gets rendered

Comment: well does your `setChildNodes` get called? What does it set the `childNodes` to? Also, I'm assuming you purposefully omitted the part of the function that returns the JSX, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped the last code in the component? This is necessary. And what about `childNodes`? This needs to be rendered, right? I think you mean something like this (untested):

```
function TreeNode({ id, name }) {
  const [childNodes, setChildNodes] = useState(null);

  function fetchJSON(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
      }
      return res.json();
    });
  }

  function fetchChildNodes(id) {
    return fetchJSON(`someUrl/${id}`);
  }

  function loadDataOnlyOnce() {
    fetch(`someUrl/specficId`).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
      }
      return res.json()
    }).then(result =>
      setChildNodes(result.map(node => <TreeNode {...node} />))
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadDataOnlyOnce();
  }, []);

  // Toggle our display of child nodes
  const toggleExpanded = useCallback(() => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
    fetchChildNodes(id).then(result =>
      setChildNodes(result.map(node => <TreeNode {...node} />))
    );
  });
  return childNodes;
}

ReactDOM.render(<TreeNode />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But it's weird you are recursively rendering. Don't know if that works. Why not have a parent component that fetches the data and passes data to all TreeNodes as children?

Comment: This still does not work. The reason I recursively render is because I have a large dataset, and it takes a while to render.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it can't render because the real rendering of the component is never defined in this code. There is no information how TreeNode has to look like. It just renders itself for the next node. That does not make sense. Therefore I think you need to declare a component that returns how a Node actually looks like (depending on if it is open or closed) and a parent component, that renders the nodes. You can still have a logic that only a few nodes get fetched or rendered.